# A Kleppner Question in rotational mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I cannot get my head around as to which force makes the ring go up at all. I have checked the solution manual where the tension is made zero in the bead and ring equations of motion and solved along with applying energy conservation. I had further read somewhere that the normal force changes when the bead reaches the angle where it is supposed to fall off but I cannot quite understand it.

[image][image]

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

After sliding down through an angle θ without friction, the kinetic energy of each bead is: (1/2)m$v^2$ = mgR(1 - cos θ). To move along the circular ring requires a centripetal force: m$v^2$/R = mg cos(θ) + N.  The reaction force on the ring is  N = 2mg(1 – cos θ) – mg cos(θ).  The lift provided by the vertical components of N from both beads (while θ is less than 90 degrees) is L = 2mg[2 – 3 cos( θ)] cos(θ).   Find cos(θ) for maximum lift and then use that to find minimum m.

Comment: Thank you but  I am familiar as to how the question is solved. The point of inquiry is how does the normal force have a vertical component acting upwards?. As the normal is acting on the beads in reaction to a component of their weight. Since this reaction is on the beads and not on the ring how can it rise the ring?

Comment: There are two normal forces: one from the ring acting on a bead, and the equal and opposite reaction force of the bead acting on the ring.

Comment: Did you get it or not